# Returns more than one row subquery error

Tags: mysql

The database records actions and time spent on matters.
The actions are recorded in the table matterjunactions where the time is recorded as a decimal in the field ‘howlong’ and the hourly fee stored in the field ‘fee’. They are linked to the matters table by matterid. When a set of actions have been billed the field ‘billed’ reads ‘Y’

I have a page that is producing a report from a number of tables including the tables above. It works fine until I try to add the sum of howlong*fee for all of those actions where billed=’N’ when I get the ‘Subquery returns more than 1 row’ error.

The code I have added to get the totals (which is the one that gives the error) is:

```
(Select ROUND((SUM(howlong*matterjuncactions.fee)),2)
                   FROM matterjuncactions JOIN matters ON 
matters.matterid=matterjuncactions.matterid
                  WHERE matterjuncactions.billed='N' GROUP BY matters.matterid) AS nonbillsum
```

The whole query is:

```
SELECT `ref`, nickname, type, statusnsteps, finalemail, bible, (matterjuncoriginals.sent) AS origsent, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT staff.initials SEPARATOR '; ') AS lds, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(matterjuncupdate.updatedate,'%D %M %Y'),' - ',matterjuncupdate.who) AS uptext, (Select GROUP_CONCAT(distinct initials SEPARATOR ', ')
                   from matterjuncstaff INNER join staff on staff.staffid = matterjuncstaff.staffid
                  where matterjuncstaff.lead = 'N' AND matterjuncstaff.matterid = matters.matterid) AS otstf, 
(Select ROUND((SUM(howlong*matterjuncactions.fee)),2)
                   FROM matterjuncactions JOIN matters ON matters.matterid=matterjuncactions.matterid
                  WHERE matterjuncactions.billed='N' GROUP BY matters.matterid) AS nonbillsum
FROM matters 
LEFT JOIN matterjuncstaff ON matterjuncstaff.matterid = matters.matterid AND lead = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN staff on matterjuncstaff.staffid=staff.staffid
LEFT JOIN matterjuncupdate ON matters.matterid=matterjuncupdate.matterid
LEFT JOIN matterjuncoriginals ON matters.mattercode=matterjuncoriginals.mattercode
LEFT JOIN matterjuncactions ON matters.mattercode=matterjuncactions.mattercode
WHERE `state` = 'Open' AND type='1'
GROUP BY matters.matterid
ORDER BY nickname ASC
```

I have looked at a number of answers to the ‘Subquery returns more than 1 row’ error but they haven’t helped me. I accept that my code is not the best but any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Query `Select ROUND((SUM(howlong .... GROUP BY matters.matterid` can result `more than 1 row` if `matterid` is not fixed.

Comment: I can't fix it as I am trying to produce a report for all open matters.

Comment: In that case you better use that subquery as a join

Comment: I'm quite new to this. How do I  do that?

Comment: you already are using joins. use the subquery as a virtual table to join.

Comment: Thank you - I'll give it a go

Comment: Sorry, I have tried a variety of ways of doing this and I just get errors. Could you demo the code for this? Thanks